# Executing a calculation on an array of symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working with and array of symbols

```
> I18n.available_locales
[:en, :it, :fr, :de]
> I18n.locale
:en
```

running an array calculation

```
> I18n.available_locales - I18n.locale
```

returns the error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Array)
```

one cannot operate on the component to calculate with to transform it into an array

```
> I18n.locale.to_a
NoMethodError (undefined method `to_a' for :en:Symbol)
```

So what is the way to  execute the calculation if the end-intent is to

```
<% I18n.inactive_locales.each do |locale| %>
   <li><%= link_to locale.to_s, { locale: locale } %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You don't transform elements into an array, you simply put them into it, i.e. `[:en]` instead of `:en.to_a`

Comment: BTW, in Rails you can use `I18n.available_locales.without(I18n.locale)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make the second operand an array too, like this (for example):

```
I18n.available_locales - [I18n.locale]
```

> So what is the way to execute the calculation if the end-intent is to

I'd probably do it inline (this way you can avoid patching I18n)

```
<% I18n.available_locales.each do |locale| %>
   <% next if locale == I18n.locale %>
   <li><%= link_to locale.to_s, { locale: locale } %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because [operator](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2D) - needs an array

try

```
2.2.10 :003 > [:a,:b,:c] - [:a]
 => [:b, :c]
```

In your case would be something like

```
I18n.available_locales - [I18n.locale]
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you can use `Array()` method

```
Array(I18n.locale)
#=> [:en]

Array([I18n.locale])
#=> [:en]

Array(nil)
#=> []

I18n.available_locales - Array(I18n.locale)
#=> [:it, :fr, :de]
```

*Reference:* https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Array.html